# Magento CE 1.9.1 - Multiple Swatches Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches

I've a configurable product with two attributes: Primary Color and Secondary Color.

The options names are the same in both attributes.

Supposing that I have a product with following options:

```
PRIMARY COLOR | SECONDARY COLOR
RED           | YELLOW
BLUE          | YELLOW
BLACK         | YELLOW
YELLOW        | YELLOW
```

Every product have it own photo.

If I click at "RED", my image is updated to the `Red Product with Yellow`.
If I click at "BLUE", my image is updated to the `Blue Product with Yellow`.
If I click at "Black", my image is updated to the `Black Product with Yellow`.

But, if I click at `YELLOW` (Both at primary and secondary color), my image is not updated, and an error occurres at prototype.js:828:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

In other tests, I realized that the problem is when I have same option name in more then one attribute. If I change it names, the problem stops.

Is there any solution for this? Or I will really need to have "Primary Yellow" and "Secondary Yellow" names?!

Comment: I've confirmed that the problem is realy the same name. The JS code just takes the attribute option name, not the attribute name + option name. This cause a kind of namespace problem.