# Configurable Swatches - "Some" Images not changing

Tags: configurable-product, swatches

I am trying to setup configurable swatches.  I have a configurable products with 300 underlying simple products.  I have uploaded images to all 300 simple products to allow the base image to change when I select the swatches.....however only some of the swatches force an image change.  My demo page is at:

http://www.infinityfuneralstationery.co.uk/order-of-service/infinity/classic-infinity-design-1.html

Only "Pattern 1, Colour 1" is different to any of the other images at the moment BUT if you select that and then click to "Pattern 2, Colour 1", I do not get a change.  However other swatch changes will invoke the image to swap.  Any ideas how to start debugging this problem?  From what I can see all the simple products have images, so I can't see what the problem is......Only my second week on Magento, so struggling a bit to make sense of all this....Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Gary

Comment: In case this is useful to anyone, I resolved the issue.  It seems that you can't have more than one attribute with the same value (i.e. don't set up Colour 1 and Pattern 1) as that causes configurable swatches to fail when changing the base image.  I ended up having Patters A->K and Colours 1->30.  That solved the issue!

Comment: See also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57895/magento-ce-1-9-1-multiple-swatches-problem